# Algorithm to toggle a variable but the input is continuous

Tags: c++, xbox

I am making a program that reads input from an xbox controller and I have some boolean variables in the code that need to be toggled.  I have this template for my function.

```
void toggle(bool condition, bool &variable) // Used to toggle variables
{
}
```

The condition parameter will be a button on the controller (ex. buttonA) and the variable parameter is a reference to the variable that needs to be toggled (ex. crouching)

The problem is that since the controller input is read constantly, a player cannot press and release the button fast enough that it is not read more than once, which causes the variable I am trying to toggle to just rapidly switch back and forth.  The behavior I want is that when A is pressed, the value of crouching changes to the opposite of what it is (crouching = !crouching) but I only want it to be run once when the button is pressed and wait for it to be released before the function can be called again.  I have tried but I cannot figure out an algorithm to do this.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not call this function when the button is released, instead of pressed, if that's possible?

Comment: Another approach is to sense button value changes along with button value position. You clearly want to react to a particular button transition, not merely a button position.

Comment: Be prepared to handle [contact chatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce) issues too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem with RAW input. That is why there are various types of events and their handlers OS provides. An example is `WM_KEYDOWN` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown). 
If raw input is the only option, you can have an intermediate filter, the result of which can be used to actually toggle the variable in your case.

for example, if `r,P` represents released and pressed states of button, a sequence like rrrrrrrrrrrrrrPPPPrrrrrrrrrrrPPrrrrrrrrrrrr would mean you need to toggle it when `r -> P` transition happens. may be you can have an array with as small as 2 elements and you do it like this
sample[1]=sample[0]; sample[0]=control.state;
if(sample[0]=='r' && sample[1]='P') then toogle(variable)

Also, you might try out with a bigger array to avoid any spurious noise, basically adopting a threshold based on minimum human key press duration and unput sampling rate.

Comment: Why bothering with an array where a simple counter of previous 'r' states would do...

Comment: @IgorG, that's subjective and need based. May be there is a use case that want to avoid accidental press or may be a long button press gesture.